# Like button does not update with AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, social-media-like

I am passing a collection (@feed_items) to a _feed_item partial via the :collection option and converting it to dailypost with :as => :dailypost.

Inside the _feed_item partial I rendered another partial for _like_button, and i used :locals to continue using dailypost.

Everything works fine with the database. Likes get added and taken out :) BUT

**I am trying to use (AJAX) to create.js.erb & destroy.js.erb the like button.
For some reason only the top post gets updated correctly and i have to refresh the page to see the ones below it.**

I know the solution involves assigning a unique post id to each "like" element, say "like-123", but that is where i am stuck.......

I also know that the problem may be in _feed_items.html.erb because i am passing two ids....any suggestions??

**Views**

_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items, :as => :dailypost %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

_feed_items.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= @dailypost.id %>">

  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to dailypost.user.name, dailypost.user %>
  <span class="content"><%= dailypost.content_html %></span>

  <div id="like">
    <%= render :partial => 'likes/like_button', :locals =>{:dailypost => dailypost} %>
  </div>

</li>
```

_like_button.html.erb

```
<% if like = current_user.likes.find_by_dailypost_id(dailypost.id) %>
 <%= form_for like, :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit "Unlike" %>
 <% end %>
<% else %>
 <%= form_for current_user.likes.build, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :dailypost_id, value: dailypost.id %></div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Like" %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'like_button', :locals => {:dailypost => @dailypost}) %>");
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'like_button', :locals => {:dailypost => @dailypost}) %>");
```

**Controller**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController


  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @like = Like.create(params[:like])
    @dailypost = @like.dailypost
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    like = Like.find(params[:id]).destroy
    @dailypost = like.dailypost
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.Replace the first-line in _feed_items.html.erb with this.

```
<li id="dailypost<%= dailypost.id %>">
```

and In create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb, make changes

```
$("#like").html(...)
```

To

```
$("#dailypost<%= dailypost.id%> #like").html(...)
```

This should Work.

Comment: Opps. I think it should be @dailypost.id in create.js.erv

Comment: so i changed the create.js.erb to this $("#dailypost<%= @dailypost.id%> #like").html(...) and it works in the terminal, but it wont render the unlike button. i have to refresh the page to see the change...@Abibullah Rahamathulah

Comment: Its Looking Like its working. U need to find the like button. may be try this jquery `$("#dailypost<%= @dailypost.id%>").find("#like").html(...)`

Comment: dude your the greatest!! :D. thanks alot...its all working now. @Abibullah Rahamathulah

Comment: would you be able to help me here please...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833885/ajaxified-star-rating-system-is-not-updating-correctly