# Ajaxified Star Rating System is not Updating Correctly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rating-system

**I've implemented a Star Rating System using this tutorial** http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3

**The Ajax works perfectly, until I add the Javascript that Submits the form/saves the data after a given user makes a change.**

For some reason, it will loop through all the elements on my Index Page, and Submits the correct integer value on the selected object, but then submits a bunch of NIL values on the rest. I only want it to update that ONE object.

(**How can I submit the appropriate Book ID in the Javascript?**)

New to rails please help :)

**VIEWS**

index.hrml.erb (books)

```
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <table id="book<%= book.id %>">
      <tbody>  
        <tr>  
          <td>
            <b><%= book.title %></b>
          </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td>  
            <%= book.release %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td  id="rating">     #####This is my partial for my form                 
            <%= render :partial => 'ratings/rating', :locals =>{:book => book} %>
          </td>

        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  <% end %>
```

_rating.html.erb

```
  Avg. Rating <%= book.average_rating %>

<%= form_for rating_ballot, :html => { :class => 'rating_ballot' }, :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label("value_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"1"}) %>
   <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 1, current_user_rating == 1, :class => 'rating_button') %>

   <%= f.label("value_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"2"}) %>
   <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 2, current_user_rating == 2, :class => 'rating_button') %>

   <%= f.label("value_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"3"}) %>
   <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 3, current_user_rating == 3, :class => 'rating_button') %>

   <%= f.label("value_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"4"}) %>
   <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 4, current_user_rating == 4, :class => 'rating_button') %>

   <%= f.label("value_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"5"}) %>
   <%= radio_button_tag("rating[value]", 5, current_user_rating == 5, :class => 'rating_button') %>

   <%= hidden_field_tag("book_id", book.id) %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"%>

<% end %>
```

create.js.erb & update.js.erb

```
$('table#book<%= @book.id%> td#rating').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'ratings/rating', :locals => {:book => @book}) %>");
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

rating_ballot.js

```
####This Submits the Radio Button, but Loops through every Book on the page. 

$(document).ready(function() {

    ###Submits the form (saves data) after user makes a change.

    $('.rating_ballot').change(function() {
    $('.rating_ballot').submit();
  });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :update]

  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id])
    @rating = Rating.create(params[:rating])    
    @rating.book_id = @book.id
    @rating.user_id = current_user.id
    if @rating.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:book_id])
    @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_book_id(@book_id)
    if @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: `<td  id="rating">` could be a problem, `id` attributes must be unique per page or you have invalid HTML and that can cause all sorts of strange things to happen.

Comment: Do you WANT it to loop through every book on submit? That seems odd. Can you post the actual HTML that your code produces?

Comment: no i do not want to loop through every book. i just want to submit an individual rating in my index page. It works fine until i Add the Javascript. @Beartech

Comment: So your javascript function needs some way to know what book is calling it. I'm not that great with JS, so I'm not much help there. But there is usually something like `.this` in jquery to tell it to just target the calling element.

Comment: yea i just realized that too, but I am not that great with JS either lol. Im trying to find out how to pass the id. @Beartech

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503168/twitter-bootstrap-rails-button-dropdown-no-responding-to-ajax it was a question I posted that I finally figured out myself with some help from the comments. Your actual HTML would really help me see the structure of the page. Notice in  mine I used code in the .erb file to add an index to every button. That allowed me to target just that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bcoz all the rating forms are submitted whenever any single rating is changed
Change your JS code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rating_button').change(function() {
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  });
});
```

Also above code will not work in JS loaded content.
i.e. your rating form will not be submitted once you add rating and that form is updated from create.js.erb or update.js.erb

Change it to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.rating_button', function(){
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: So in my Views, would I need to change the Class in the Form to .rating_button?

Comment: You don't need to change anything in view. I have used existing class of radiob button i.e. rating_button itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! :) Would you mind looking at this other problem I encounter after...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837113/star-rating-system-only-updates-first-book

Comment: I have added my comments, please check